# TradingView getBars JS API issue when calling onHistoryCallback (nuxtJS vueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tradingview-api

I am trying to create JS API for making trading view calls to the server
It works fine for config & resolveSymbol but I've problem in getBars

these are my javascript codes for getBars

```js
        getBars: (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback, firstDataRequest) => {
          this.$axios.$get
          (this.datafeedUrl + '/history?symbol=' +
            symbolInfo.name +
            '&resolution=' + resolution +
            '&from=' + periodParams.from +
            '&to=' + periodParams.to +
            '&countback=20')
            .then((r) => {
              let bars = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < r.t.length; ++i) {
                let bar = {
                  time: 1e3 * r.t[i],
                  close: parseFloat(r.c[i]),
                  open: parseFloat(r.o[i]),
                  high: parseFloat(r.h[i]),
                  low: parseFloat(r.l[i]),
                  volume: parseFloat(r.v[i])
                }
                bars.push(bar)
              }
              console.log(typeof bars)
              console.log(bars)
              onHistoryCallback(bars, {noData: false})
            })
          onErrorCallback((e) => console.log(e))
        },
```

This is errors I get + console.log data
[image: error tradingview]

my data format is exactly like udf(predefined JS API) of tradingview
I can't get why this happens

Comment: What is the format of `time` that you use? Maybe `time` format should be string.

Comment: As I checked it must be float and my data is exactly like tradingView demo data